# Xamarin.iOS MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to set up a dictionary for my `MKMapItem`, to open the native Map Application set to a certain location with a certain directions mode (walking, driving, transit, etc).

When I try to do the equivalent of this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey];
```

in C#, I can't find the key `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey` in Xamarin.

My `DirectionsMode` value is here, and changed according to a parameter passed to my function.

```
    MapKit.MKDirectionsMode LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode;
    switch (sMode)
    { 
      case 1:
           LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode = MKDirectionsMode.Driving;
        break;
      case 2:
           LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode = MKDirectionsMode.Driving;              
        break;
      case 3:
           LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode = MKDirectionsMode.Walking;
        break;
      default:
           LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode = MKDirectionsMode.Driving;
        break;
    }

    var emptyDict = new NSDictionary();
    var endingCoord = new CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D(sLat, sLng);
    var endLocation = new MKPlacemark(endingCoord, addressDictionary: emptyDict);
    var endingItem = new MKMapItem(endLocation);

    var launchOptions = new NSMutableDictionary();
    var t = new MKMapItem();
    launchOptions.Add(??????, LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `MKDirectionsMode` Enum.

```
launchOptions.Add(MKDirectionsMode.Driving, LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode);
```

This is found in the `MapKit` namespace.

**UPDATE**
You don't need to use a dictionary, in your case you can use the `MKLaunchOptions` class to set the directions.

```
var launchOptions = new MKLaunchOptions();
launchOptions.DirectionsMode = LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode;

endingItem.OpenInMaps(launchOptions);
```

Comment: I should have added more code to my original post sorry.
Here, LaunchOptionsDirectionsMode is already my MKDirectionsMode. I'm looking for the key MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey in Xamarin. I updated my original post to be more clear

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks !